# Save DIalogue that copies/loads another file

Tags: c#, streamwriter, savefiledialog

I am trying to save a file, but the actual file is already built and saved in a temp location, and I just want to move/copy that pre-built file to wherever the user chooses with the save dialogue.

What I have right now is this

*fileName = the pathway of the file that is already built.*

```
private void SaveFile()
        {
            SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog(); 

            savefile.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savefile.FileName))
                    sw.WriteLine(fileName);
            }
        }
```

Obviously right now this just writes the pathway to a text file, but I am trying to find a way to basically copy that file to wherever this user specifies.

Comment: copy as in `file path` or `file content`?

Comment: Read the MSDN documentation for System.IO.File, please...

Comment: @AppDeveloper the file content. So I basically make a "temp" file, then allow the user to save that somewhere by moving/copying that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like

```
if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // you can use File.Copy
    System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, saveFile.Filename);
}
```